# How could I query these 3 associated models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

Imagine these models:

```
class User
  belongs_to :profile
  # has email here
end

class Profile
  has_one :user
  # has first_name,last_name
end
```

and

```
class Post
  belongs_to :profile
  # has title,content
end
```

Now, I would like to query all posts ( do a LIKE "%substring%" ) on the user's email. I would prefer to not have to write it with map/selects as I think it would generate pretty inefficient code. I tried something like that:

```
class Post
  def self.with_user_email_like(email)
    self.joins(:profile).where("profile.email LIKE ?","%#{email}%")
  end
end
```

The thing is, I know somehow I should have a profile.user.email in the condition above, but I just can't get it to work. Any suggestions?

Comment: your posts are asociated to profile or user model? And you have email in Users table or Profile table?

Comment: Posts are associated to a Profile. Email is in the user table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
class Post
  belongs_to :profile
  scope :with_user_email_like, lambda{|email| joins(:profile => :user).where("users.email LIKE %?%", email)} 
end
```

Comment: email is in the User table. See the comment in each of the model.

Answer (score 1):

Well you are almost there, but since email is in the users table you have to join that too:

```
self.joins(:profile => :user).where("users.email LIKE ?","%#{email}%")
```